# Get access to the element durign property bind

Tags: angular

I've coulpe of input elements that look like:

```
<input
    type="text"
    name="width"
    [value]="getValue('width')"
    (input)="onChange($event)"
/>


<input
    type="text"
    name="height"
    [value]="getValue('height')"
    (input)="onChange($event)"
/>
```

For getting input value it's nessesary to past input name value. Is there any way to pass whole input as a parameter for this getValue method? (something like $event?)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

.ts

```
  height: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.height = this.getValue("height");
  }

  getValue(type) {
    return 10;
  }
```

.html

```
<input
      type="text"
      name="height"
      [(ngModel)]="height"
      (input)="onChange($event)"
    />
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k3qcxk?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

You can choose one from two options. [Template-driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms) or [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

For example:

```
<input
type="text"
name="height"
[(ngModel)]="height"
(input)="onChange($event)"/>
```